# Hide a listbox but still allow hover on visible element

Tags: html, css, select, hide

I'm trying to hide a select listbox, which is working fine, but I'd still like the hover effect to work on the visible element but it isn't.  Here's a simple fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Kr6E9/

The top box has the hover working properly, but no listbox inside.  The bottom box has the hidden (actually, opacity set to 0) listbox but the hover doesn't work except for where the listbox isn't.

Is there anything I can do about this?

Amazon does this same thing on their homepage with their main search box (that defaults to All).  I've looked and they have a hidden listbox, and their hover works, but they must be doing something I'm not.  It doesn't appear to be a z-index issue and from what I can tell there is no way to programmatically activate the listbox options.

Ideas? Thanks for the help!

(Oh, and my positioning is really terrible for the example, I will do a much better job of placing the listbox, but I think this was the simplest way to show my problem).

To appease the parser, here's some example html of the list node.  Note that this can change if necessary:

```
<span class="wrapper">
  <span class="text">Select</span>
  <select class="dropdown">
    <option>123</option>
    <option>234</option>
    <option>345</option>
  </select>
</span>
```

Thanks again!

Comment: A "listbox" is a "select".

Answer (score 0):

Remove this:

```
.text:hover {
background-color: lightgray;
}
```

Add this:

```
.wrapper:hover > .text{
background-color: lightgray;
}
```

Whenever the `wrapper` is hovered on, this style is applied to all the child `text` elements.